# Built-in Firewall in android

Tags: android, firewall

I need to capture incoming TCP packets on rooted android device. Does android offer a built-in firewall? how to use it to capture incoming TCP packets from an already known IP address?

Comment: Definitely not possible unless your device is rooted. If it is rooted, I don't know.

Comment: This is possible and there are a few apps on the store that do it even without root access. For example "Packet Capture". I think it uses Androids VPN functionality to "become the man-in-the-middle".

Comment: @Thomas How can we do it for rooted device?

Answer (score 1):

Use TcpDump in your rooted phone, This will save pcap file, which you can export and open in wireshark to analyse network traffic

[Compiled TCP Dump for Android x86 exmulators](https://github.com/aniqueazhar/TCPDUMP-for-X86-emulators)